# On-click color change and dimensions of figure [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming and I've been doing an online course for a few weeks now. I have to do a program that has (3) points. Make a figure that transforms into a square and to a rectangle, make it change to various colors on click and at last, write dimensions of figure on screen.
Last night I got the first 2 points to work, but now when I call `JQUERY` it makes all the page go blank. `

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var color = ["Red", "Pink", "SkyBlue", "Grey", "Purple", "Orange"]; 

ctx.fillStyle = color [Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

var posicion = 0;
var tamano = 0;
var clicks= 0;    

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400-tamano);

    posicion++;
    tamano++;

    if (posicion > 400){
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
    }
}, 30);
```

`

I call JQUERY using this code, but now it doesn't seem to work.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
$("canvas").click(function(){
   ctx.fillStyle=color [Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have proper markup for the `jQuery` call. You are missing  the `closing` `brackets`, `parentheses` and a `semicolon` at the end `});`.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var color = ["Red", "Pink", "SkyBlue", "Grey", "Purple", "Orange"]; 

ctx.fillStyle = color [Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];

var posicion = 0;
var tamano = 0;
var clicks= 0;    

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    
    // this was added
    var tamanoWidth;
    if((tamano + posicion) < 400) tamanoWidth = tamano;
    else tamanoWidth = 400 - posicion;
    
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamanoWidth, 400-tamano);
    
    // output to div
    $("#dimensions").html("Width: " + tamanoWidth + "<br/>Height: " + (400-tamano));
    
    posicion++;
    tamano++;
    if (posicion > 400){
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
    }
}, 30);

$("canvas").click(function(){
    ctx.fillStyle=color [Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<div id="dimensions"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I still have doubts on how to return the current image size on canvas. I know I have to declare <p></p> and  call jquery using something like this  `$("largoalto").text(posicion, tamano);` But I don't really know how to apply it

Comment: @VanessaDurán I edited to add the dimensions output. Your image was getting wider and wider inside the canvas, I fixed it now by using an if statement to check the current position and width of the image and to change the width so the image is always fully shown inside the canvas. After running the snippet scroll down to find the output.